# data binding not displaying data using InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have simple workflow where employee can request for product. This product submission was designed in Infopath. Manager then gets to Approve or Reject this Decision. I added tasks to Manager using "Collect Data from User" action in SPD, where I added Reject or Approve Checkboxes. But, I also want to design a form where he can also see who is the requester of Product, Product information which are stored in the List (lets say ListA) that this Workflow runs on.

For this, I click on the ManagerApproval.xsn in Forms box in SPD. Then I added new data connections to ListA, and selected option to get required information. Then, I added requesterName, productName etc in the form using queryFields. There are queryFields and dataFields, what is the difference between them ?

I then publish the form, but it doesn't display any value only empty text boxes, when Manager is approving the Request. Don't know whats wrong ? Thanks

EDIT : Using datafields, I can see the data. But, I see id of the product not the value (eg I see 1,2 not ProdA, ProdB). And, also I see the whole list of products in ListA, I only intend to see values for the current item. There is something like repeating section in Infopath form, when I drag fields into Form. How can I filter it to show values (infact only 1 value - 1 product name, 1 requstername not the whole list from previous requests and already completed) for the current item ?

OR Alternatively, is there any way to design Custom Form for Manager Approval using Infopath, so that this form can be called inside Workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

query fields - are field names, which are defined in XML schema,
data fields are actual data

**Use data fields instead of query fields**.

When you create a connection you get data from SharePoint XML something like the sample below.
In this     -  contains the query fields: ows_LinkTitle

Node  contains the data.

```
- <xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
- <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
    - <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
    -   <s:AttributeType name="ows_LinkTitle" rs:name="Title" rs:number="1">
         <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" /> 
        </s:AttributeType>
      </s:ElementType>
  </s:Schema>

- <rs:data>
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="Central Programme Office" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="Communications" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="Educational Resources" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="Finance" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="General Practice" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="IT" /> 
  <z:row ows_LinkTitle="Web and Branding" /> 
  </rs:data>
  </xml>
```

Comment: Using datafields, I can see the data. But, I see id of the product not the value (eg I see 1,2 not ProdA, ProdB). And, also I see the whole list of products in ListA, I only intend to see values for the current item. There is something like repeating section in Infopath form, when I drag fields into Form. How can I filter it to show values (infact only 1 value - 1 product name, 1 requstername not the whole list from previous requests and already completed) for the current item ?

Comment: Ok so you can modify your data connection and include additional columns. Bu default ID alone is selected. The additional column then should be available in 'dataFields' when you modify entries.

Comment: No, I already have selected additional columns. I dragged these columns to form. And I get this repeating section thing, which displays all products, and display their Ids, not its name. By the way, these products are stored in another lists and I get their names in ListA using lookups.